# OpenCV Face Detection Forced Closed...?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, android-camera

I work on face detection using Opencv library 2.4.5
I solved all error and also give NDK path and Opencv path to demo project....but when I run this project on device it forced closed...I refered all the questions on this topic in stackoverflow but can't find the proper solution...

Android.mk file is given below...

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include C:/ANotherWork/OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android.mk file as shown below, its missing the value for LOCAL_PATH

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
    include C:/ANotherWork/OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
    LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

    LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: can use please post the error you get in logcat when the application is force closed

Comment: Using Camera Emulator will be not worked...so its going to only `RuntimeException` that is acceptable ,but when i use Device than it will be closed....

Comment: application will be closed, fine.You should also be seeing a logcat error when the application is closed. please post that here, its hard to findout why the app closes with out knowing the error.

Answer (score 0):

check this link.. its a easy implementation(No Opencv)

http://www.edumobile.org/android/face-detection-example-tutorials-in-android/